# How to preview list before filling the listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to display a list of a layout item before loading the actual items from Firebase.

Something like-

[image: listpreview]

I have tried:

```
tools:listfooter="@layout/item_footer"
    tools:listheader="@layout/item_header"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item"
```

But none of this seems to work.

Please explain if there's a way out or if some library can do that.

Comment: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-design-shimmer-effect-fa7f74c68a93

Comment: That's a better alternative thanks